# Installing MULE ESB mule-standalone-3.3.1

Tags: installation, mule, chef-infra, esb, mule-studio

Can some guide me .. for installing Mule ESB(mule-standalone-3.3.1) in Ubuntu . I am unable to find any documentation for installing. i want to automate it through Chef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's can be as simple as downloading and unpacking the archive file from: http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone-3.3.1.zip

**Note**: You need jdk 6/7 installed first.

Here's a chef cookbook that does this: https://github.com/ryandcarter/mule-cookbook

And here's a Vagrant script for running the mule cookbook on ubuntu etc: https://github.com/ryandcarter/vagrant-mule

Comment: thanks for the reply . but after downloading the tar/zip file . what are the configurations .. we are supposed to do .

Comment: Nothing to get it up and running. Just run ./bin/mule to start it up and then start deploying your applications. It's that simple. You can configure it more if you need to by editing wrapper.conf etc. or you can run it as a service etc. More info here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2INTRO/Running+Mule

Comment: u mean to say run this command (./bin/mule )  and check it in the browser. but while automating it through chef.. there is nothing to install and configure .

Comment: yep. There's is nothing else to install or configure if your happy with the standard setup. Browser? only if your apps have http endpoints in them that will respond to get requests.

Comment: my requirement is to automate the mule esb (mule-standalone-3.3.1). Yes in browser .. or is der an other way to check whether its working ..??

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
Download and unpacking the archive file from: http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone-3.3.1.zip or whatever version you want to install.

put this unpack file to anywhere where you want like `/opt/` or `/usr/local/`

put you mule application inside apps folder.

& go to bin directory and run `./mule` start command. Now mule server is running. You can also check mule log inside log folder mule.log file

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case there are others who are looking.
You want to install Mule as a Ubuntu Service, so that it restarts when The server restarts.  There are a couple of basic steps to this

I detailed out instructions and installation files at my github repository 
https://github.com/jamesontriplett/mule_linux_service_install

Steps in general:

1. Install a startup script in /etc/init.d
2. Install a startup parameter file in /etc/mule
3. Customize parameters in the wrapper.conf file in /conf/wrapper.conf
4. Install the license file onto the server if using enterprise
5. Add the startup script to the run levels.

To test, you want to reboot the linux service to make sure that it will come back after a reboot. If it doesn't you have a reliability issue.